# tmux/zsh messes up pasted text

Tags: zsh, tmux, clipboard

When I paste text into a tmux shell running zsh by select it with a mouse and then hitting 3rd mouse button, it prefixes the text with "200~" and adds a "~" at the end.  For example, if I have the text "some text" marked, tmux will paste in "200~some text~" instead.

I'm on Debian with tmux version 2.0 and zsh 5.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From zsh's `README`

> ### Incompatibilites between 5.0.8 and 5.1
>
> The default behaviour when text is pasted into an X Windows terminal
>   has changed significantly (unless you are using a very old terminal
>   emulator that doesn't support this mode).  Now, the new "bracketed
>   paste mode" treats all the pasted text as literal characters.  This
>   means, in particular, that a newline is simply inserted as a visible
>   newline; you need to hit Return on the keyboard to execute the pasted
>   text in one go. See the description of zle_bracketed_paste in the
>   zshparams manual for more.  "unset zle_bracketed_paste" restores the
>   previous behaviour.